# Export is not recognize

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-appservice, azure-cloud-shell

I would like to install dot.net package but the export is not recognized in Azure App Service.

```
wget -q -O - https://dot.net/v1/dotnet-install.sh | bash -s -- --version 3.1.102
export PATH="\~/. github.com/JaneFun/JaneFun/tree/main:$PATH"
echo "export PATH="\~/. 
github.com/JaneFun/JaneFun/tree/main:$PATH":$PATH" \>\> \~/.bashrc
```

However, it is not successful and appeared with this error:

> export: The term 'export' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program.
>
> Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its working.

[image]

Which version you are using, Could you try this in the current version of the Azure CLI is 2.34.1.

For information about the latest release, see the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/release-notes-azure-cli). To find your installed version and see if you need to update, run [az version](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/reference-index?view=azure-cli-latest#az_version).